# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I am migrating my .NET standard 2.0 class library application to .NET core 3.0 where I want to start web API server from class library, Where class library application is getting launched with executable.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>true</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.6.10" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When class library application is getting launched with executable It throws error like below.

> Creating of instance of type
> 'MySampleDll' failed: Could not load
> file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions,
> Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

When I download Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from nuget package and manually keep the library in output directory. It throws new error saying Microsoft.AspNetCore 3.0.0 could not be found.
Please help me what I am doing wrong.

[image: List of SDKS installed]

Comment: What is your target framework now? Make sure you have selected .net core 3. Which version of VS you have? Do you have .net core 3 SDK?

Comment: Visual studio 2019 16.7.7. Target Framework is .Net core 3.0

Comment: I have attached the image for list of SDK's installed in my workstation

Comment: Why do you want to migrate?

Comment: I want to add web API server in my class library so I thought of migrating and using WebHostBuilder for the same.

Comment: you can create a new .net core project and refer to this class library

Comment: Means I have to create another class library application with target framework .net core 
 3.0 with webhostbuilder and add the generated output library to .net standard class library application as reference right ?

Comment: update to VS16.8.6, target .net core 3.1 as 3.0 is out of support and reference the 3.1.12 version of the lib

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, it's not needed any more, as explained in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references).

Also, consider upgrading to .NET Core 3.1 instead, which is an LTS version. .NET Core 3.0 [has already reached end of life and is no longer supported](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.0).